# how to extract string by Regex with grep?

Tags: awk, sed, grep, regular-expression

say I have a SQL.txt

```
select * from table1;
select a,b,c from table2 where a=1;
```

How can I filter the table name with the command `cat SQL.txt|grep`

My expected output is:

```
table1
table2
```

I'm a newbie to `grep` command, I appreciate for any help. Thanks.

### Update

What I want is knowing how to apply the regex into `grep` command.

for this case, I can write the regex: `from (.*?)`. The problem is I don't know how to use regex with grep

Comment: What can we rely on? Should we search for the word `table` followed by a single number? Can you also have tables called `table12`? Or `tableFoo`? or `notatableatall`? Should we instead look for the word `from` and take the next word as the table? Will the `from` always be there? Please [edit] your question and clarify what you need. Is your input really only those two lines?

Comment: @terdon , thanks for your comment. I have updated the question

Comment: This assumes that all your queries use a single table and there are no queries such as `SELECT ... FROM TABLE1, TABLE2 ...`, not mentioning `SELECT ... FROM TABLE1 T1, TABLE2 T2 ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grep simply takes a pattern and a file as arguments. As explained in `man grep`:

```
GREP(1)                          User Commands                         GREP(1)

NAME
       grep, egrep, fgrep - print lines that match patterns

SYNOPSIS
       grep [OPTION...] PATTERNS [FILE...]
       grep [OPTION...] -e PATTERNS ... [FILE...]
       grep [OPTION...] -f PATTERN_FILE ... [FILE...]

DESCRIPTION
       grep  searches  for  PATTERNS  in  each  FILE.  PATTERNS is one or more
       patterns separated by newline characters, and  grep  prints  each  line
       that  matches a pattern.  Typically PATTERNS should be quoted when grep
       is used in a shell command.
```

So, the general format is `grep 'regex' file`. So, to use your example regex, you would do:

```
grep 'from (.*?)' file
```

That won't work, however, since `grep` uses [Basic Regular Expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) (BRE) which don't treat parentheses as special characters<sup>1</sup> and don't understand the non-greedy (find the shortest match) `*?` operator. What you actually want is:

```
grep 'from [^[:blank:]]' file
```

That uses the BRE character class `[[:blank:]]`, but *negates* it with the `^` (`[^[:blank:]]`) so that it now matches any non-whitespace character. This is still not what you need, however, since `grep` will return the entire matching *line* and not only the portion of the line which matched.

If you have GNU `grep` (the default on Linux), you have the `-o` option which tells `grep` to only return the matching portion:

```
$ grep -o 'from [^[:blank:]]*' file 
from table1;
from table2
```

Of course, this is still not what you need, there's an extra `from`, a space and a trailing `;` in one of them. Once more, if you have GNU `grep`, you can use PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) which support [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=from )\w+' file 
table1
table2
```

Here, the `-o` tells `grep` to only return the matching portion and the `-P` enables PCRE support. The `(?<=from )` is called a *positive lookbehind* and means "only match the next part if the previous part matches `from`". Finally, the `\w` is a special PCRE class that matches "word characters": letters, numbers and `_` (and a bit more, if using Unicode). As explained in `man perlre`:

```
\w        [3]  Match a "word" character (alphanumeric plus "_", plus
               other connector punctuation chars plus Unicode
               marks)
```

PCREs also have the nifty `\K` feature. This is like a lookbehind but basically means "ignore anything that matched up to here". Using that, we can simplify the regex above to:

```
$ grep -oP 'from \K\w+' file 
table1
table2
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. so grep doesn't have the group concept, like extracting any part you want.

Comment: @DennisLi GNU `grep` does, with the `-o` option as I explained in my answer. And it also supports capture groups (parentheses) when using a regular expression flavor that supports them such as PCRE (`-P`). But the parentheses don't do what you think they do: they don't mean "print only this", they just mean "capture this so we can use it". For example, this works: `echo foofoo | grep -oP '(f..)\1'`: it matches `f` and any two characters, followed by a repetition of what was matched (`\1`). But all this is way beyond the scope of a simple Q&A site. Please read some documentation instead.

Comment: Thanks your for your explanation. it's clear:)

Answer (score 0):

Tried with AWK command with no piping ,Tested and worked fine

```
 awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /^table/){gsub(";","",$i);print $i}}}' file
```

output

```
table1
table2
```

Comment: awk can do the substitutions that you're currently piping to sed...

Comment: Done and corrected